# SQL Server output as XML all on one line

Tags: sql-server, xml

I'm using SQL Server 2014 and I'm new to XML.  I'm trying to export 3 tables into XML.  The 3 tables are:

Property (Parent)
PropertyArea (Child)
PropertyNotes (Child)

In SQL world, there is a left join from:

Property > PropertyArea
Property > PropertyNotes

The primary and foreign key is [property_id]

I have the below SQL code.  However, when I open it in Notepad ++ it just creates the XML all on one line, and I was expecting to see it formatted.

```
DECLARE @XMLOutput XML
DECLARE @XMLOutputChar nvarchar(max)

;WITH XMLNAMESPACES('MyNameSpace' as ns)

SELECT @XMLOutput =
(
SELECT ISNULL(T1.[propertyusercode],'')AS propertyusercode, 
       ISNULL(T1.[NAME],'')AS [NAME],
    (
        SELECT
        (
        SELECT 
        [AreaCode]
        ,[AreaDesc]
        FROM [PropertyArea]
        WHERE [Property_Id] = T1.property_id 
        FOR XML PATH('Area'), TYPE
        )
        FOR XML PATH('Area'), TYPE
    ),
    (
        SELECT
        (
        SELECT 
        [NotesModuleNumber]
        ,[NotesPageNumber]
        ,[NotesText]
        FROM [PropertyNotes]
        WHERE [Property_Id] = T1.property_id
        FOR XML PATH('Notes'), TYPE
        )
        FOR XML PATH('Notes'), TYPE
    )
FROM   Property T1 


    FOR XML PATH('Property'),TYPE, ROOT('Loader'),ELEMENTS XSINIL
)

SET @XMLOutputChar = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>' + CONVERT(nvarchar(max),@XMLOutput)

SELECT @XMLOutputChar AS XMLOutput
```

Am I missing something?  Is my code correct?

Comment: You mean "formatted" as in with line breaks and easy to read? SQL Server won't do this for you. You can use Notepad++ plugins (like XML Tools) to do this. Software that use XML don't need them to be *pretty*.

Comment: Ah I see, silly me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to see it on Notepad++, use plugin **XML Tools** to "pretty print" the XML into an easier to read format.

[image]

Copy paste from SQL Server:

[image]

After formatting:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this - one thing - its doesn't appear as a blue hyperlink in my SSMS (v17.4)

Comment: @Michael My screenshot is from a SSMS version 2008R2 (10.5). Old habits die hard I guess.